# How to write human-readable data to to a JSON file

Tags: python, json, unicode, character-encoding

When I export a file from python to json file it contains charecters like,

```
{"-": "text", "menu": {"-": "node", "id": 2244676, "prev": "[2/40] \u0d2a\u0d4d\u0d30\u0d2f\u0d4b\u0d1c\u0d15 \u0d15\u0d4d\u0d30\u0d3f\u0d2f
```

I used

```
with open('messages.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(all_messages, outfile, cls=DateTimeEncoder)
```

in python. How to convert it to normal unicode text?

Comment: Show some code??

Comment: I added more code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the output JSON to be human-readable, use UTF-8 encoding and the `ensure_ascii=False` parameter:

```
with open('messages.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
        json.dump(all_messages, outfile, cls=DateTimeEncoder,ensure_ascii=False)
```

If you just want to read the data back in again, `json.load` will convert it back to Unicode:

```
with open('messages.json', encoding='utf8') as infile:
    data = json.load(infile)
```

Examples with simple strings:

```
>>> s = '[2/40] പ്രയോജക ക്രിയ'
>>> print(json.dumps(s))
"[2/40] \u0d2a\u0d4d\u0d30\u0d2f\u0d4b\u0d1c\u0d15 \u0d15\u0d4d\u0d30\u0d3f\u0d2f"
>>> print(json.dumps(s,ensure_ascii=False))
"[2/40] പ്രയോജക ക്രിയ"

>>> out = json.dumps(s)
>>> out
'"[2/40] \\u0d2a\\u0d4d\\u0d30\\u0d2f\\u0d4b\\u0d1c\\u0d15 \\u0d15\\u0d4d\\u0d30\\u0d3f\\u0d2f"'
>>> json.loads(out)
'[2/40] പ്രയോജക ക്രിയ'
```